# Old OPOS debug CCOs anywhere?

Tags: opos

I've got customer systems that absolutely have to run 1.11 OPOS. There are debug CCOs around for that version but they pulled all the old stuff off the main site a while back. Anyone know where they might be found?

Answer (score 0):

When the fixed versions of the 1.14.000 and 1.13.001 memory leak bugs were released, earlier versions were no longer posted on the MCS site.
[MCS: OPOS Common Control Objects - Current Version](http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm)

> Releases 1.14.001 and 1.13.003 corrected a memory leak issue and a potential buffer overrun issue.  Therefore, we recommend that users upgrade to one of these releases.
>
> Because of these issues, older releases have been removed from the page.

There should be nothing published now.
For debugging purposes, it does not apply to the actual store environment, so may you use the latest version (1.14.001) of the debug version?
That would fit the MCS recommendations.

Or, if you really need a debug version of 1.11.xxx, find someone who still holds it, or send a request email to the MCS site administrator.

---

**In Addition:**

Your question may be an XY problem.
[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Instead of asking for a debug version of the CCO, ask the actual problem you are encountering.

Alternatively, even if you do not have a debug version of the CCO, if you have the call/return log on the application side and the entry/exit log on the service object side, you can check the situation by comparing them.

Comment: I think what happened in 1.13 was they removed the implementation of objects prior to 1.11. But 1.11 implements earlier versions as well and my customer has a system that is fairly old. Hence 1.14 won't work. I've tried emailing the site but no response.

Answer (score 0):

Monroe Consulting were kind enough to provide an archived copy. Problem solved.